# FaultException in sending big amount of data in WCF?

Tags: wcf

I have a long xml file the content of the file are below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://example.org/person</a:Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <OrderDataBDO xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BasWare.OM.BusinessDataObjects">
            <selected i:type="x:boolean" xmlns="">false</selected>
            <isSaved i:type="x:boolean" xmlns="">false</isSaved>
            <metadata i:nil="true" xmlns=""/>
            <hasUnsavedValues i:type="x:boolean" xmlns="">false</hasUnsavedValues>
            <hasChanged i:type="x:boolean" xmlns="">false</hasChanged>
            <defaultResourceId i:type="x:string" xmlns="">BWRc.OM.BUSINESSOBJECTS.ORDERDATABDO.ORDER_DATA</defaultResourceId>
            <_x0031_ xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BasWare.ProductFramework.BDOFramework" i:type="d4p1:ADate" xmlns="">
                <_x0031_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0031_>
                <_x0032_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0032_>
                <_x0033_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0033_>
                <_x0034_ i:nil="true"/>
                <_x0035_ i:type="x:boolean">true</_x0035_>
                <_x0036_ i:type="x:dateTime">1753-01-01T12:00:00</_x0036_>
                <_x0037_ i:type="x:string">d</_x0037_>
                <_x0038_ i:type="x:string">ActualDeliveryDate</_x0038_>
            </_x0031_>
            <_x0032_ xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BasWare.ProductFramework.BDOFramework" i:type="d4p1:AString" xmlns="">
                <_x0031_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0031_>
                <_x0032_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0032_>
                <_x0033_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0033_>
                <_x0034_ i:nil="true"/>
                <_x0035_ i:type="x:boolean">true</_x0035_>
                <_x0036_ i:type="x:string"/>
                <_x0037_ i:nil="true"/>
                <_x0038_ i:type="x:string">BuyerCode</_x0038_>
            </_x0032_>
            <_x0033_ xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BasWare.ProductFramework.BDOFramework" i:type="d4p1:AID" xmlns="">
                <_x0031_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0031_>
                <_x0032_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0032_>
                <_x0033_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0033_>
                <_x0034_ i:nil="true"/>
                <_x0035_ i:type="x:boolean">true</_x0035_>
                <_x0036_ i:type="x:string"/>
                <_x0037_ i:nil="true"/>
                <_x0038_ i:type="x:string">BuyerId</_x0038_>
            </_x0033_>
            <!--etc-->
            <_x0034_6 xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BasWare.ProductFramework.BDOFramework" i:type="d4p1:AMoney" xmlns="">
                <_x0031_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0031_>
                <_x0032_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0032_>
                <_x0033_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0033_>
                <_x0034_ i:nil="true"/>
                <_x0035_ i:type="x:boolean">true</_x0035_>
                <_x0036_ i:type="x:decimal">0</_x0036_>
                <_x0037_ i:type="x:string">N2</_x0037_>
                <_x0038_ i:type="x:string">TaxSum</_x0038_>
            </_x0034_6>
            <_x0034_7 xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BasWare.ProductFramework.BDOFramework" i:type="d4p1:AString" xmlns="">
                <_x0031_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0031_>
                <_x0032_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0032_>
                <_x0033_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0033_>
                <_x0034_ i:nil="true"/>
                <_x0035_ i:type="x:boolean">true</_x0035_>
                <_x0036_ i:type="x:string"/>
                <_x0037_ i:nil="true"/>
                <_x0038_ i:type="x:string">Text1</_x0038_>
            </_x0034_7>
            <_x0034_8 xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BasWare.ProductFramework.BDOFramework" i:type="d4p1:AString" xmlns="">
                <_x0031_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0031_>
                <_x0032_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0032_>
                <_x0033_ i:type="x:boolean">false</_x0033_>
            </_x0034_8>
        </OrderDataBDO>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Why would you think it necessary to post the entire message?

Comment: So, what's the problem? Please post the complete exception.

Comment: thanks John , John can u pls create a sample wcf app with one method which takes one string parameter and prints it.
Then from client please pass the above xml which i have posted , and call the method on service , u will see the exception and maybe will have more idea about my prob. Please try it.

Comment: As most of the folks here have said, you need to post the exception.  It will help us help you.  We're making guesses right now.

Comment: My answer as the answer of other people, assumed that this Xml is the dump of the message, but you are saying that the Xml is passed as string data to a WCF service. Why are you doing this?
Anyway the message is not really big, just 4k, so the problem must be unrelated to size.

Comment: following is the message:

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:msg. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.IO.MemoryStream. The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 44708.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set various of your settings - play around with the values, and see which work.

First, use whatever binding you're using and tweak the `<readerQuotas>` (maxStringContentLength, maxArrayLength, maxNameTableCharCount) - if that works, fine!

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeMessages">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, you'll need to create your own custom binding in config, and set the limits on the message level as well - something like this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="ExtraLargeMessages">
          <textMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
              maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096"
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </textMessageEncoding> 
          <httpsTransport 
              maxBufferPoolSize="1048576"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576"
              maxBufferSize="1048576"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Hope this helps.

Marc

**UPDATE:**
I would tryto add this behavior to your service, and then call the method again.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DetailedDebug" >
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="yourService" behaviorConfiguration="DetailedDebug">
        .....
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

You should now get detailed exception info on your client - can you tell us what it is?? Maybe it's something totally different.......

Marc

Comment: thanks  marc_s , i tried all the settings but it doesn't work.

Comment: updated with "serviceDebug" behavior to find out what the error REALLY is.

Answer (score 0):

Change your [Max Message Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbindingbase.maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx) (for example, depending on your binding) on the client and server as [described here](http://kennyw.com/indigo/70).

Something else may be going wrong.  Can you [enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) for WCF and use the [trace log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to narrow down the exception?

Comment: i have changed the settings as below :
 <readerQuotas maxDepth="100" maxStringContentLength="33200" maxArrayLength="33178"
                        maxBytesPerRead="10000" 
maxNameTableCharCount="33178" />
but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the number of objects: try adding something like this

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="PutTheNameOfYourBehaviorHere">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

to your config file.

Comment: thanks Giulio , Giulio can u pls create a sample wcf app with one method which takes one string parameter and prints it. Then from client please pass the above xml which i have posted , and call the method on service , u will see the exception and maybe will have more idea about my prob. Please try it.

Comment: following is the message: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter tempuri.org/:msg. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.IO.MemoryStream. The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 44708.'. Please see InnerException for more details.